# Count down timer in php with database

Tags: php, html, mysql

How can I insert an count down timer in an form using PHP?

And I want to storage that target time into my mysql db. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? Please ask a proper question.

Comment: Is your space bar broken?

Comment: You can store target time in mysql as unix timestamp. As for countdown, you need javascript for that. Google something like 'javascript countdown', I don't think anyone will help you given how much effort you put into the question.

Comment: Are You saying about how many time has been taken by the user to fill form ?

Comment: Please specify your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the target time in Mysql and you can fetch that target time in PHP and assign it to Javascript code, so the javascript will show the countdown timer.

For countdown timer you can take any jquery script from here:
http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/11/jquery-countdown-scripts.html